# Udacity Intro to computer science: Lesson 7 Exercise 2

Tags: python, computer-science

Here is how I answered the question below. How would I solve this question better?

**

> Define a procedure, stamps, which takes as its input a positive
>   integer in pence and returns the number of 5p, 2p and 1p stamps (p is
>   pence) required to make up that value. The return value should be a
>   tuple of three numbers(that is, your return statement should be
>   followed by the number of 5p, the number of 2p, and the number of 1p
>   stamps). Your answer should use as few total stamps as possible by
>   first using as many 5p stamps as possible, then 2 pence stamps and
>   finally 1p stamps as needed to make up the total. (No fair for USians
>   to just say use a "Forever" stamp and be done with it!)

**

**Here is my solution**

```
def stamps(i):
    # Your code here
    five = 0
    two = 0
    one = 0
    while i > 0:
        if i == 0:
            break
        if i >= 5:
            five = five + 1
            i = i - 5
        if i == 0:
            break
        if i < 5 or i == 2:
            two = two + 1
            i = i - 2
        if i == 0:
            break
        if i < 2 or i == 1:
            one = one + 1
            i = i - 1
    return five,two,one
```

Here are the tests in the exercise

```
print stamps(8)
#>>> (1, 1, 1)  # one 5p stamp, one 2p stamp and one 1p stamp
print stamps(5)
#>>> (1, 0, 0)  # one 5p stamp, no 2p stamps and no 1p stamps
print stamps(29)
#>>> (5, 2, 0)  # five 5p stamps, two 2p stamps and no 1p stamps
print stamps(0)
#>>> (0, 0, 0) # no 5p stamps, no 2p stamps and no 1p stamps
```

Comment: If the code works, the question is *probably* (consult their guidelines) more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com. If the code *doesn't* work, you'll need to be specific about where the expected result differs from the actual result.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The code works. As a newbie just wondering how if the code could be written better. I will look into posting it in codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use modulo and remainder operations:

```
def modulo_and_remainder(a, b):
    return a//b, a %b

def stamps(a):
    five, rem = modulo_and_remainder(a, 5)
    two, one = modulo_and_remainder(rem, 2)
    return five, two, one
```

Alternatively (didn't even know this) you can use builtin divmod:

```
def stamps(a):
    five, rem = divmod(a, 5)
    two, one = divmod(rem, 2)
    return five, two, one
```

Comment: +1, although there already is a built-in function [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) that does what you do with `modulo_and_remainder`.

Answer (score 0):

To make this a bit more generic, a function that takes a tuple of stamp types:

```
def stamps(postage_cost,stamps):
        stamps_required = []
        for stamp in stamps:
            (num_stamps,remainder) = divmod(postage_cost,stamp)
            stamps_required.append(num_stamps)
            postage_cost = remainder
        return tuple(stamps_required)

stamp_types = (5,2,1)
required = stamps(8,stamp_types)
print(required)
```

Answer (score 0):

`def stamps(x):
    return (x / 5, (x - x / 5 * 5) / 2, x - (x / 5 * 5 + (x - x / 5 * 5) / 2 * 2))`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might find this in the future, I feel as though the provided solutions aren't particularly beginner friendly, seeing as this is a CS101 course.

I believe this is the solution Udacity is looking to guide you towards, given the available tools at the time. At the very least, this is the answer I came up with as a complete programming beginner.

```
def stamps(x): # Your answer should use as few total stamps as possible
five = 0
two = 0
one = 0
while x > 0:
    if x == 0:
        break
    while x >= 5: # Maximizes usage of 5 pence stamps
        five = five + 1
        x = x - 5
    while x >= 2: # Maximizes usage of 2 pence stamps
        two = two + 1
        x = x - 2
    if x >= 1: # The remainder
        one = one + 1
        x = x - 1
return (five, two, one)
```